# Understanding $\chi^2$ test results

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

I have a little trouble understanding the results of a $\chi^2$ test. I have the following statistics about people suffering accidents treated at hospitals or clinics.

```
         | dies | survives
hospital |  53  | 218
clinic   |  46  | 825
```

Based on the lecture notes Excel computes $53.2$ for $\chi^2$ value from the table. The degree of freedom is $1$, level of confidence is $5%$, the expected $\chi^2$ value is $3.841.$ Because $53.2$ is greater than $3.841$, the null hypothesis is invalid, so - what does it mean? The chance of surviving is *not* independent of the place of treatment? Common sense from the data suggest that patients in the clinic have better chances, so it seems right and I think I understand this example.

However, I have an other example about coffee consumption and marital status:

```
consumed coffee (mg/day)
             | 0   | 1-150 | 151-300 | >300
married      | 678 | 1567  | 612     | 253
divorced     | 69  | 121   | 102     | 86
single       | 284 | 344   | 163     | 97
```

I did the same calculations with Excel and got $157.9$ for $\chi^2$. The degree of freedom is $6$, level of confidence is $5%$, the expected $\chi^2$ value is $12.59.$ Because $157.9$ is greater than $12.59$, the null hypothesis is invalid, so - what does it mean? The coffee consumption is *not* independent of marital status? Married people are less likely to drink $151+$ mg/day coffee than divorced people?